# Laravel-Lumen Api response with wrong timezone date

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, lumen

My API save the correct timezone date in MySql database for example: `2018-01-05 13:05:02`, but when I fetch the data I receive wrong timezone date: `2018-01-05 10:05:02`?

I have changed the `APP_TIMEZONE: UTC` to `APP_TIMEZONE: Asia/Baghdad` as well and its not working too, what I'm missing here.

Comment: Maybe you should also check your `mysql` timezone.

Comment: @DharmaSaputra I already set it `SET time_zone = '+03:00';` but same results